# Multiple background images in fabricjs

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am building a new app with fabricjs,
in this I need

1. User controlled multiple background images in which behave like normal image, user can rotate, drag resize it,
   it done some stuff like this for multiple BG,

   ```
   // 1st img
   var img = new Image();
   img.onload = function(){
    canvas.setBackgroundImage(img.src, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas), {
           originX: 'left',
           originY: 'top',
           left: 100,
           top: 100
       });
   };
   img.src = "site_image/temp/zig3.jpg";

   // 2nd img
   var img1 = new Image();
   img1.onload = function(){
    canvas.setBackgroundImage(img1.src, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas), {
           originX: 'left',
           originY: 'top',
           left: 300,
           top: 300
       });
   };
   img1.src = "site_image/temp/zig1.jpg";
   ```

   But first BG is replaced by second one,
   multiple backgrounds controlled by user are possible or not?
2. One more issue I faced,
   I have JSON of fabricjs, which include an image(normal image not background),
   when I will show it to user I want that this image will become background of canvas,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use an absolute path in that JSON file and use AJAX to change the background image. Also, you can follow this [link][1] for a JSFiddle example.

[1]: https://jsfiddle . net/manish1706/qxnh4j53/